# Django CSRF missing or incorrect Ajax POST without jquery (Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, ajax, asynchronous

when i got this error when i was using jquery i simple do:

```
data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{csrf_token}}"}
```

Now I'm trying to move to vanilla JavaScript, here is my ajax call

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.querySelector('#sendMessage').onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    alert('success')
                    let response = this.responseText
                    console.log(response)
                } else {
                    console.log(this.status)
                    console.log(this.readyState)
                }
            };
            xhr.open("POST", "{% url 'chat:room' room.id %}", true);
            // Send data csrf_token, content, area
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            data = {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                'content': document.querySelector('#id_content').value,
                'area': parseInt(document.querySelector('#id_area').value),
            }
            console.log(data)
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
</script>
```

However i get this error:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /chat/room/3/
[04/Oct/2020 05:25:16] "POST /chat/room/3/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
```

I have been searching for a while but all answers are solving it for jquery not vanilla js, Any help?

Update

Views.py:

```
def room(request, room_id):
    room = get_object_or_404(Room, pk=room_id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {'room': room})
    else:
        print(request.POST)
        message = Message.objects.create(
            user=request.user, content=request.POST.get('content'), room=room)
        message.save()
    return JsonResponse({})
```

Comment: Can you verify `csrf_token` in console and check from the cookie from browser ?

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong in the csrf token, here is what i get when i print the data    { csrfmiddlewaretoken: "qYzbJCEZ6LGrhEySpbetbdJlRwdjYrTmtgZ6NV6WKAsJ2R5l3W2Hs3z0LTuSTAQo", .....

Comment: What about checking csrf from django side?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do so, the only thing I tried is to print(request.POST), and it didn't do anything as the only thing I got in the terminal was CSRF missing.

Comment: For debugging, uncomment all `request.POST` and Do: print(request.POST['csrfmiddlewaretoken'])` and see the terminal. Also, please update your `views.py` in the post. It might be helpful.

Comment: Interesting, I did csrf_exempt and found out that the data is not passed to the server-side in both GET and POST, but Why? I think i need to do some google searching

Comment: have you tried setting `X-CSRFToken` request headers ? like `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set additional request header for CSRF:

```
# code

xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}');

#code
```